# Not able to navigate to a page from root page in xamarin forms ios app

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, prism

I have a Xamarin forms app which is developed using Prism.
The problem that i am facing in IOS is I am not able to navigate to CreateAccount Page from below method.But the same code is working in UWP perfectly.

```
  protected async override void OnInitialized()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
        await NavigationService.NavigateAsync($"NavigationPage/LoginPage");
    }

 protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry 
 containerRegistry)
    {
     containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<CreateAccount, CreateAccountViewModel>();            
   containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<LoginPage,LoginViewModel>();
   containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<ForgotPassword>();
   }
```

When I replace the above line like below the navigation is happening but ViewModel is not getting registered.

```
 containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<CreateAccount>();
```

### AppDelegate.cs

```
[Register("AppDelegate")]
public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
{        
    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
        LoadApplication(new App(new iOSInitializer()));

        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    }

}

public class iOSInitializer : IPlatformInitializer
{

    public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {            
    }
}
}
```

### CreateAccountPageViewModel:

```
public class CreateAccountViewModel : BasePageViewModel, 
INavigationAware
 {  
  public static INavigationService _navigationService;

  public CreateAccountViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
        : base(navigationService)
     {
    _navigationService = navigationService;
    }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: did you try removing the $ before NavigationPage/LoginPage and checked?

Comment: yes i tried by removing $ before NavigationPage/LoginPage but its still not working @hashimks

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Try to register `NavigationPage` in the `RegisterTypes`.

```
  protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry
containerRegistry)
        {
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<CreateAccount, CreateAccountViewModel>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<LoginPage, LoginViewModel>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<ForgotPassword>();

            //add
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<NavigationPage>();
        }
```